# True + True = 2. Elegantly perform boolean arithmetic?

Tags: python, boolean, boolean-operations

I have nested lists of truth values representing SAT forumlas, like this:

```
[[[0, True, False], [0, True, False], [0, True, 1]], [[0, True, True], [2, True, True], [3, False, True]], [[1, False, False], [1, False, False], [3, False, True]]]
```

representing

```
([x0=0] + [x0=0] + [x0=1]) * ([x0=1] + [x1=1] + [-x2=1]) * ([-x3=0] + [-x3=0] + [-x2=1])
```

I would like to calculate the truth value of the whole formula. First step would be adding up the truth values of the literals in each clause.

like this:

```
clause_truth_value = None

for literal in clause:
    # multiply polarity of literal with its value
    # sum over all literals
    clause_truth_value += literal[1]*literal[2]
```

if `clause_truth_value` is `True` after the summation, the clause is true as a whole.

But I am not getting what I expected:

`True + True = 2` that's not as expected

`True * True = 1` that's as expected

`False + False = 0` that's as expected

`False * False = 0` that's as expected

so... True is simply 1 and False is 0... that sucks, I expected the arithmetic operators to be overloaded for the boolean algebra. Is there an elegant way to do do boolean arithmetic with boolean variables?

Comment: Boolean operators are `|` and `&`, not `+` and `*`

Comment: But there is no `+=` like `and=`. So....

Comment: Instead of using `x += y`, you can use `x = x or y`

Comment: @lotolmencre There's always the bitwise versions; `x &= y` and `x |= y`. Those aren't lazy, though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Python, `True == 1` and `False == 0`, as `True` and `False` are type `bool`, which is a subtype of `int`. When you use the operator `+`, it is implicitly adding the integer values of `True` and `False`.

```
int(True)
# 1

int(False)
# 0
```

What you really want is to treat `True` and `False` as binary numbers.

```
int(False & False)
# 0

int(True & False)
# 0

int(True & True)
# 1
```

From [Bitwise Operators in Python](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators):

> x & y
>
> Does a "bitwise and". Each bit of the output is 1 if the
>   corresponding bit of x AND of y is 1, otherwise it's 0.
>
> x | y
>
> Does a "bitwise or". Each bit of the output is 0 if the corresponding bit of
>   x AND of y is 0, otherwise it's 1.

Comment: Note that lists are unsupported operand types for `&` & `|`, but `and` and `or` will work.

Answer (score 5):

There is a way to do boolean arithmetic.  That way is to use boolean operators.

- and, as you call "*", is `and`.
- or, as you call "+", is `or`.