# I am trying to understand a python function that takes a list and rearranges the elements in the list

Tags: python

I am trying to understand what `change += change >= i` does in this python code. The purpose of this code is to take a list and return it but with rearranged element positions.

```
import random
def random_shuffle (lst):
    len1 = len(lst)
    for i in range(len1):
        change = random.randrange(len1 - 1)
        change += change >= i
        lst [i], lst[change] = lst[change], lst[i]
    return lst
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this out in the Python REPL easily:

```
>>> 4 + (3>1)
5
>>> 4 + (3>5)
4
```

And see [True + True = 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38276843/true-true-2-elegantly-perform-boolean-arithmetic).

A more typical way to write `change += change >= i` might be:

```
if change >= i:
    change += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

`change >= i` is either `True` or `False` depending on whether the comparison is true or false.

When a boolean is used where a number is needed, `True == 1` and `False == 0`. Depending on the condition, it's either `change += 1` or `change += 0`.

So it's equivalent to:

```
if change >= i:
    change += 1
else:
    change += 0
```

Since adding `0` to a number has no effect, it could be further simplified to

```
if change >= i:
    change += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

so i goes from i to the length of the list.  then change gets assigned to a random number between 0 and length of the list -1

'>=' has greater precedence than '+=' so look at the '>=' i first

so if change is greater than i it returns True.

Then look at +=,  change += True adds 1 to change,  change += False adds zero to change

Then the last line swaps the two items.