# Return the right string according to the condition

Tags: python, return

I try to solve the following problem

Write function `bmi` that calculates body mass index (`bmi = weight / height ^ 2`).

**Return values based on the calculated `bmi` value:**

```
if bmi <= 18.5 return "Underweight"

if bmi <= 25.0 return "Normal"

if bmi <= 30.0 return "Overweight"

if bmi > 30 return "Obese"
```

**My code:**

```
def bmi(weight, height):
    b = weight / height ** 2
    return ['Underweight', 'Normal', 'Overweight' , 'Obese'][(b <= 18.5) + (b <= 25) + (b <=30)]
```

I get a wrong answer anyone know where is the mistake ?

Comment: What is your understanding of `['Underweight', 'Normal', 'Overweight' , 'Obese'][(b <= 18.5) + (b <= 25) + (b <=30)]`, what does it do?

Comment: isn't that pointed the wrong way?

Comment: `True` is equal to the integer `1`. If you want your indexing to make sense, you need to either make the list in reverse order, or flip the conditions of your checks (i.e. from `b <= 18.5` to `b > 18.5`)

Comment: shouldn't it be >=?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about the actual output of the following statement:

```
(b <= 18.5) + (b <= 25) + (b <=30)
```

if `b` is 18, then all 3 will be true, so the output will be `3` - "Obese". If `b` is 24, then the second and third condition will be true, so the output will be `2` - "Overweight". If `b` is 29, then only the third condition will be true, so the output will be `1` - "Normal". If `b` is 31, then none of them will be true, so the output will be `0` - "Underweight".

A solution would be to reverse your array:

```
['Obese', 'Overweight', 'Normal', 'Underweight'][(b <= 18.5) + (b <= 25) + (b <=30)]
```

Or, you can reverse your conditions, so that the original order would work:

```
['Underweight', 'Normal', 'Overweight' , 'Obese'][(18.5 <= b) + (25 <= b) + (30 <= b)]
```

In this case, if `b` is 18, then `(18.5 <= b)` is `False`, `(25 <= b)` is `False`, and `(30 <= b)` is `False`, so the output is `0`, "Underweight". If `b` is 24, then `(18.5 <= b)` is `True`, `(25 <= b)` is `False`, and `(30 <= b)` is `False`, so the output is `1`, "Normal". If `b` is 29, then `(18.5 <= b)` is `True`, `(25 <= b)` is `True`, and `(30 <= b)` is `False`, so the output is `2`, "Overweight". Lastly, if `b` is 31, then `(18.5 <= b)` is `True`, `(25 <= b)` is `True`, and `(30 <= b)` is `True`, so the output is `3`, "Obese".

Comment: yeah that's right 
thanks man
where can i read more about this ?

Comment: Read more about what exactly? This is just basic Python syntax involving comparison operators. You could read a basic Python book to familiarize yourself with the simple, commonly used parts of the language, but I don't have a particular one to suggest to you. My solution just involved thinking about the logic and executing it in my head, and seeing what the results would be just via simple reasoning. If you don't understand what your own code does, then you definitely should read a basic Python book.

Comment: yeah that's right I was just not quite aware that True + True = 2  It sounded a little strange to me because I'm just started  learning the basics of Python .

Comment: @MarwanAkram Here's an explanation of why that happens: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38276843/true-true-2-elegantly-perform-boolean-arithmetic However you were already adding booleans together in your code, so it's not clear why you weren't aware of what would happen when you added them.